# Google + Page adding a follower directly into a specific circle

Tags: google-plus

I have created a google + account and added a business page so i now have a page id. this page has multiple circles public, traders, business etc.

i have then added the Google api to my site for people to follow my page and for me to add them to a circle, but it has become clear that i now cant tell which circle a new follower should be in. is there a way of adding followers directly into a specific circle from my website.

please help as this is driving me crazy or am i'm missing the point some how?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google+ Badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) is currently the only way to change the circles people are in without visiting [plus.google.com/circles](https://plus.google.com/circles). There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9) for access to circle through the API you can star if you would like such a method added.